# How to re-implement a Where() operator for PLINQ?

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, plinq

I'd like to rewrote one of my `LINQ` extensions to take advantage of parallelism. Anyway, I don't know where to start.

As a teaching example, **I'd like to know how to rewrote implementation of a `Where()` operator, but that work on `ParallelQuery`.**

```
public static ParallelQuery<TSource> Where<TSource>(
   this ParallelQuery<TSource> source, 
   Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    //implementation
}
```

It would be possible to write :

```
someList.AsParallel().Where(...)
```

Writing a `Where` that is performed in serial is trivial :

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>( 
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate) 
{ 
    foreach (TSource item in source) 
    { 
        if (predicate(item)) 
        { 
            yield return item; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I had in mind to simply wrap the predicate around a `Parallel.ForEach()` (and pushing results in a List/Array) but I don't think that is the way to go.

I don't know if it is trivial to write (so it can fit as a SO answer) or it is very complex. If so, giving some hints from where to start is also good. There is probably several ways to implement that and it can probably become very complex because of specific optimizations but a simple implementation that works will be ok (which means it provide correct results and is faster than non multithreaded implementation above)

---

As suggested by Scott Chamberlain, here is implementation of LINQ method i'd like to rewrite :

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereContains<TSource, TKey>(
     this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
     IEnumerable<TKey> values,
     Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> elements = new HashSet<TKey>(values);

    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        if (elements.Contains(keySelector(item)))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could always start by [seeing how .NET does it](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/System/Linq/ParallelEnumerable.cs.html#1d9778d5d3a2de7d).

Comment: Totally unrelated, but a sneaky optimization trick: change your first line to `ISet<TKey> elements = values as ISet<TKey> ?? new HashSet<TKey>(values)`. That way if the source you passed in for `values` was already a set based class you don't need to do the extra conversion (if you are on 3.5 instead of 4.0 you can replace the `ISet<TKey>`s with `HashSet<TKey>`s). **Edit:** I removed my comment because you updated your question and did not want to clutter up the comments with stuff that was no longer relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make your own `ParallelQuery<T>` based classes unfortunately due to the fact that while `ParallelQuery<T>` is public it does not have any public constructors.

What you can do is use the existing PLINQ infrastructure to do what you want. All you really are wanting to do is do a `Where` with a `Contains` being the predicate... So do that.

```
public static ParallelQuery<TSource> WhereContains<TSource, TKey>(
    this ParallelQuery<TSource> source,
    IEnumerable<TKey> values,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> elements = new HashSet<TKey>(values);

    return source.Where(item => elements.Contains(keySelector(item)));
}
```

This performs the `Where` clause in parallel, and (while not documented) `Contains` is thread safe as long as you are not performing any write operations, and because you are making a local HashSet to perform the lookup you don't need to worry about writes happening.

---

Here is a example project that prints out to the console what thread and item it is processing, you can see that it is using multiple threads.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> items = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(0,100));

        int[] values = {5, 12, 25, 17, 0};

        Console.WriteLine("thread: {0}", Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);

        var result = items.AsParallel().WhereContains(values, x=>x).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

static class Extensions
{
    public static ParallelQuery<TSource> WhereContains<TSource, TKey>(
        this ParallelQuery<TSource> source,
        IEnumerable<TKey> values,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        HashSet<TKey> elements = new HashSet<TKey>(values);

        return source.Where(item =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("item:{0} thread: {1}", item, Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);
            return elements.Contains(keySelector(item));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a lot of fun digging around the reference source trying to figure this out. Turns out it was a lot easier than I thought!

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just do this?

```
public static ParallelQuery<TSource> Where<TSource>(
    this ParallelQuery<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    return
        source
            .SelectMany(x =>
                predicate(x)
                ? new TSource[] { x } 
                : Enumerable.Empty<TSource>());
}
```